# Annotation processor not found using Android studio 0.8.9, gradle plugin 0.13, android-apt plugin

Tags: annotations, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm writing an Android library which has to use an Annotation Processor. But unfortunately I can't build my processor due to javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor not found during the compile task.

I'm using gradle 2.1, android studio 0.8.9, Android studio 0.8.9, gradle plugin 0.13, android-apt .

I created a sample project with just one AbstractProcessor accessible here. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9sIyspkcsJzVWRNS3BfdWFPV1k/edit?usp=sharing

I also checked in Android studio if there is an option to enable Annotation processing, but found nothing in the compiler section.

Do you know how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found defining another java project containing the processor.